# Methods for solving definite trig. integrals?

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am studying Fourier series and there is a lot of integration going on, specifically with trigonometric functions involved. When solving for the Fourier coefficients, often times, the definite integral of a trig. function (such as $f(x)= |sin(x)| cos(x), f(x)=sin^2(x), f(x)=cos(x), etc.$) cancels out to be zero.

I know the criteria for defining whether a function is even or odd, can I somehow use that, in addition to looking at the bounds of an integral to determine whether solving it would make everything cancel and the result equal to zero? Are there any specific rules or criteria that predict cancelation?

Comment: $\sin^2(x)$ doesn't integrate to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deciding if a function is odd or even is very useful for Fourier series.

- If $\mathrm{h}$ is an even function then $\displaystyle{\int_{-L}^L\mathrm{h}(x)~\mathrm{d}x = 2\int_0^L\mathrm{h}(x)~\mathrm{d}x}$
- If $\mathrm{h}$ is an odd function then $\displaystyle{\int_{-L}^L\mathrm{h}(x)~\mathrm{d}x = 0.}$

We also need to remember that

- even $\times$ even = even
- odd $\times$ even = odd
- odd $\times$ odd = even

**EVEN FUNCTIONS**

The Fourier series of an even function will have only cosine terms. There are no sine terms because sine is odd and even $\times$ odd = odd, which means a zero contribution from the integral - see above.
$$\mathrm{f}(x) = \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos\!\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$
where
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_0 &=& \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L \mathrm{f}(x)~\mathrm{d}x \\ \\
a_n &=& \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L\mathrm{f}(x)\cos\!\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\mathrm{d}x 
\end{eqnarray*}

**ODD FUNCTIONS**

Similarly, the Fourier series of an odd function will have only sine terms. There will be no cosine terms because cosine is an even function and odd $\times$ even = odd, which means a zero contribution from the integral - see above.
$$\mathrm{f}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n\sin\!\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$
where
$$b_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L \mathrm{f}(x)\sin\!\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: One addendum to this nice answer: It's not uncommon to run into Fourier analysis on an interval which is not symmetric about 0 (e.g. $[0,2L]$). In that case, while symmetry considerations certainly apply, they're with respect to the interval's midpoint. (An obvious thing when one says it, but it can be forgotten in practice.)

Comment: @Semiclassical If you think it's a "nice answer", then why not up-vote it ;o)